# String interpolation working with python

Tags: python

I am new to learning how to use string interpolation in strings and am having trouble getting this example I am working with to actual print the right results.

I've tried to do:

```
print "My name is {name} and my email is {email}".format(dict(name="Jeff", email="me@mail.com"))
```

And it errors saying `KeyError: 'name'`

Then I tried using:

```
print "My name is {0} and my email is {0}".format(dict(name="Jeff", email="me@mail.com"))
```

And it prints

```
My name is {'email': 'me@mail.com', 'name': 'Jeff'} and my email is {'email': 'me@mail.com', 'name': 'Jeff'}
```

So then I tried to do:

```
print "My name is {0} and my email is {1}".format(dict(name="Jeff", email="me@mail.com"))
```

And it errors saying `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

It should give me the following output result back:

```
My name is Jeff and my email is me@mail.com
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the call to `dict`:

```
>>> print "My name is {name} and my email is {email}".format(name="Jeff", email="me@mail.com")
My name is Jeff and my email is me@mail.com
>>>
```

Here is a reference on the syntax for [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: Thanks. So you don't have to use dict?

Comment: @user3079411 - No, not with `str.format`.  If you have a dictionary though, you can index it like @hwnd demonstrated.  But in your case, the call to `dict` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `[]` (`getitem`) operator.

```
>>> print "My name is {0[name]} and my email is {0[email]}".format(dict(name="Jeff", email="me@mail.com"))
My name is Jeff and my email is me@mail.com
```

Or use it without calling `dict`

```
>>> print "My name is {name} and my email is {email}".format(name='Jeff', email='me@mail.com')
My name is Jeff and my email is me@mail.com
```